# Maximum of polynomials on unit sphere

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Let $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a polynomial of degree $n$, i.e.
$$
f(z) = \sum_{k = 0}^n a_kz^k.
$$
I suppose that when looking for the $\max$, we can flip around coefficients:
$$
\max_{\lvert z \rvert = 1} \lvert f(z) \rvert = \max_{\lvert z \rvert = 1} \left \lvert \sum_{k = 0}^n a_k z^{n-k}\right \rvert
$$
I have confirmed this for the case $n=1$. Is there an easy proof for the case $n>1$? I also know that $\max_{k = 1, ..., n} \lvert a_k \rvert \leq \max_{\lvert z \rvert = 1} \lvert f(z) \rvert$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true, since, assuming that $|z|=1$,\begin{align}\left|\sum_{k=0}^na_kz^{n-k}\right|&=\left|\sum_{k=0}^na_kz^{-k}\right|\text{ (since $|z^n|=1$)}\\&=\left|\sum_{k=0}^na_k\left(\frac1z\right)^k\right|\end{align}and$$\left\{\sum_{k=0}^na_k\left(\frac1z\right)^k\,\middle|\,|z|=1\right\}=\left\{\sum_{k=0}^na_kz^k\,\middle|\,|z|=1\right\}.$$

Comment: Thank you! How exactly is the first equality derived?

Comment: You have$$\left|\sum_{k=0}^na_kz^{n-k}\right|=\left|z^n\sum_{k=0}^na_kz^{-k}\right|$$and then you use the fact that $|z^n|=|z|^n=1$.

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaah. Thank you, easier than it looks...